# Google analytics I'm a novice

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I've got someone doing SEO for me and would like to no is it possible there manipulating visitors to show higher page views as I'm in UK and normaly Google search alone is 85% then yesterday it was 9% and the rest are site32 and sclick could this be deliberate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.. Such a huge difference in a day is quite impressive or simply duplicitous.

- Have a look at the geographical distribution of the visitors. The more diverse the distribution the less likely it is that there is foul play.
- Are you using the service of a proven company or a miracle worker that you met at Starbucks?
- Did your SEO guy tell you that you have to keep using his services to keep your numbers good and steady?

Comment: 15 different country's and it's the same guy that built my website contracting the work out just want value for money and i really am a beginner when it comes to this ! Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Is your site verbose? Is it a blog with lots of articles? If yes, the average visit will be as long as 3 to 5 minutes.

How long is the average visit?

Comment: No its a business site in the services industry and the bounce rate on that day was 97% when it's usually 40% or lower !